# Does Jesus eat food in heaven?

Tags: biblical-basis, heaven

Jesus said there will be no marriage in heaven, but after He rose He ate food. Does Jesus eat food in heaven? Is there any reason for us to suppose He does not?

This is the kind of question kids ask me in Sunday School.

Comment: I'd ask whether they think of heaven as a physical or a metaphysical reality, and get them to hone their ideas around food (spiritual or material) accordingly. The philosophical exercise could also be applied to Jesus pre- and post-resurrection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I must admit, I chuckled at `This is the kind of question kids ask me in Sunday School.`. Anyway...

First off, Revelations 19 has a wedding *feast*.

> [**Revelation 19:9 (NIV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2019:9&version=NIV)
>   <sup>9</sup> Then the angel said to me,   “Write this:   Blessed are those who are invited to the **wedding supper** of the Lamb!”   And he added, “These are the true words of God.”

(Emphasis mine.)

You can't really have a *feast* without food or drink. There is also the promise of Jesus that He will not drink wine again until this very same feast.

> [**Matthew 26:29 (NLT)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+26:29&version=NLT)
>
> <sup>29</sup> Mark my words—I will not drink wine again until the day I drink it new with you in my Father’s Kingdom.”
>
> [**Mark 14:25 (NLT)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+14:25&version=NLT)
>
> <sup>25</sup> I tell you the truth, I will not drink wine again until the day I drink it new in the Kingdom of God.”
>
> [**Luke 22:18 (NLT)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+22:18&version=NLT)
>
> <sup>18</sup> For I will not drink wine again until the Kingdom of God has come.”

This statement takes place immediately after Jesus offers wine and bread at the first Communion. Now, if there weren't any grapes in Heaven, could there be wine? Now, obviously, God could very easily simply produce wine on the spot, and a miracle should never be excluded from the set of possibilities.

Now to actually answer your real question: we can't really know. I know of no verse that talks about whether or not there is any food or drink being consumed in Heaven right *now*. That said, what is there to keep Jesus and other people already up there from enjoying the gift of eating that God gave them? I mean...I could totally imagine Jesus munching on some fish with Peter, James, and John right now...

Comment: @Jas3.1 Please [join me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26085/discussion-between-andrew-and-jas-3-1-re-the-wedding-feast-and-the-great-feast-o)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to argue "**yes**, most likely", but from an unorthodox perspective.

The Biblical picture of "Heaven" is a lot different than our modern idea of it.  When everything prophesied in Scripture is said and done, we are not going to float on clouds playing harps, or dissipate into spiritual la-la land... we are going to live on a new earth.  ([examples](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=%22new%20earth%22&qs_version=NASB))  The picture is one of redemption.

Since there was food in the garden prior to sin, and it was all "very good", I suspect there will be food in "Heaven" (i.e. on the new earth) once the original design is redeemed.

Comment: The answer hardly qualifies as "unorthodox". 20th and 21st century theologians have spent a great deal of time trying to change popular impressions of heaven to be less otherworldly along similar lines.