# What happens in Heaven when we come into contact with fellow Christians who don't wish to speak to us in this life?

Tags: heaven, kingdom-of-heaven, fellowship

Let say for one reason or another, we have friends whom we've drifted apart from in our lives, and they also happen to be Christians. We're all going to meet each other in Heaven, but does the Bible say anything about our unresolved tensions and how we'll see each other from then on?

Comment: `friends ....drifted apart....unresolved tensions` doesn't make much sense to me. It is my belief we will be happy to see everyone we can in heaven

Comment: What doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: What do you think might be the case between Paul and Barnabus ? _And the contention was so sharp between them, that they departed asunder one from the other: and so Barnabas took Mark, and sailed unto Cyprus;_ [Acts 15:39] Such things happen and they will be resolved by the Lord himself when he returns. Surely ?

Comment: Revelation21:27, "nothing defile shall enter". If we have not yet perfected charity, sorry we are not worthy to enter Heaven. The most intriguing part for me, is what will happen to all Christian if they saw the Blessed Virgin Mary, is the Highest Creature in Heaven beside the King Jesus Christ, remember Mary is the Queen of Heaven and Earth.

Comment: @Nigel Paul resolve it in this life, how? He no longer lives, but Christ lives in him. St.Paul perfected charity  by perfecting the holy virtues imitating Christ perfectly.(Galatians2:20)

Answer (score 1):

This is in the realm of speculation, but for sure any Christian in heaven has already been sanctified completely so assuming that we and our friends "make it to the end" and enter heaven, there will be so much goodwill and catching up and learning of why we drifted apart on earth but then immediately forgive each other then focus our attention to have eternal great fellowship while enjoying the presence of God that all causes for drifting apart on earth would have vanished into insignificance.

C.S. Lewis's [The Great Divorce](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083QNYY94), [study guide here](http://www.cslewis.org/resources/studyguides/Study%20Guide%20-%20The%20Great%20Divorce.pdf), has imaginative scenarios of this kind of meeting, including meeting a murderer who has repented.

Comment: Is Heaven a place for sanctification or glorification? Nobody can enter Heaven who is not in a perfect or unblemished state. Book of Revelation teaches only those who wash their robe, and no spot no matter how small it is. "Nothing defile shall enter God's Kingdom"(Revelation21:27)

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs I said the same thing: "any Christian in heaven has **already** been sanctified completely... "  And yes, we would have been glorified as well.  I'm just focusing on the "being sanctified" portion, which enabled us to forgive easily.

Comment: You stated; "there will be so much goodwill and catching up and learning of why we drifted apart on earth but then immediately forgive each other.."Glorified souls do not do this in Heaven anymore, beatific vision was only given to those who perfectly purged & finished their purification. "Blessed are the pure for they shall see God", because "nothing defile shall enter the KIngdom of God".(Rev21:27)

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs I also said that "this is in the realm of speculation".  Glorified soul refers to the glorified body we will have; it doesn't mean we lose our memory of earthly living.  After all, having memory of past issues doesn't have to be painful if you forgive.  After resurrection, didn't Jesus have glorified body?  Didn't Jesus not have memory of Peter having betrayed Him and thus the dialog in [John 21:15-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+21%3A15-17&version=NLT) ?

Comment: After resurrection, did Jesus have "glorified body" or "resurrected body". Glorification is only in Heaven, Jesus need to ascend first into Heaven for Him to have a "glorified body". Look at the description of Jesus appearance in the Second Coming and the "resurrected body". Is there a difference?

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs I don't think we can know for sure, not enough data.  But I lean toward Jesus's having glorified body before ascension, as [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/8378/10672) says according to St. Thomas Aquinas.  But your point about how He looks at second coming is well taken as THAT might be the glorified body, or maybe it's a special case because He is God as well as human.  Who is to say He needs to appear as human at the second coming?

Comment: We are sure it is written in gospel and Jesus showed it, the glorified body can be seen in the Transfiguration. The resurrected body was not yet transfigured or glorified.

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs  You may be right, and I do not wish to argue with you further.  God bless !

Answer (score 1):

I use to have "anxiety" and still do (at times) as to how can I have joy and peace in heaven when I know that here on earth some of my friends and loved one's have died without knowing Jesus Christ.

Then the Lord gave me Revelation 21:4-5, "and He shall wipe away every tear from their eyes; and there shall no longer be any death; there shall no longer be any mourning/sorrow, or crying, or pain; the first things have passed away."

Verse 5, "And He who sits on the throne said, "Behold I AM MAKING ALL THINGS NEW. And He said, Write, for these words are faithful and true." When "glory" comes, all I want to see is "smiles" and "rejoicing." Hope this helps!